# Partial ordering of natural numbers

Tags: relations

[image]How can I prove that the partial ordering of natural numbers has no least element? 
I genuinely have no idea how to do this. Q3c. This is not a homework/assignment task. It's a past exam paper which I am attempting to solve in preparation for my exam

Comment: Which partial ordering? If you use the "normal" way to order natural numbers 0 (or 1 depending on what your set of natural numbers contain) will be the least element. Or do you mean integers?

Comment: @OveAhlman edited the question mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a "least element" I assume you mean an element $X$ such that every element $Y$ satisfies $Y≥X$?   But given $x\in \mathbb N$  consider the element $x+1$.  We can't have $x≤x+1$ in your system since $2x$ is never less than $x+1$ in $\mathbb N$.

I believe that some people use "least element" to refer to an element $x$ such that there is no element $y≠x$ with $y≤x$.  That is a much weaker notion.  In this case, $x=1$ works with your partial ordering.

Comment: that makes sense! the first paragraph is the one i'll use.

Comment: how can i solve 3b?

Comment: Same example works.  In this order, $x$ and $x+1$ are not comparable.